# Как отправить margin ордер в binance используя язык PHP?

Tags: php, api, binance

Пользуюсь [данной библиотекой](https://github.com/jaggedsoft/php-binance-api) но в ней не предусмотрена возможность работы с изолированной маржой. Есть ли возможность работать с binance margin на php?

Возможно есть готовые PHP решения?

Сейчас в библиотеке код такой:

```
public function marketBuy(string $symbol, $quantity, array $flags = [])
{
    return $this->order("BUY", $symbol, $quantity, 0, "MARKET", $flags);
}

$quantity = 1;
$order = $api->marketBuy("BNBBTC", $quantity);
```

Может как-то дописать можно? Спасибо!

Comment: Возможно тут не все знают про binance. Поэтому расскажите как сделать то, что вы хотите, без php. Там же [API](https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs). Значит то, что вы хотите делать -- это один или несколько запросов в этот API. Какие?

Comment: Здесь описан данный метод, вроде бы то, что мне нужно...  https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#margin-account-new-order-trade Хочу ордер с кредитным плечом отправлять.

Comment: Искусственный интеллект (до чего техника дошла) подсказал альтернативную либу https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt У них хорошая [дока](https://docs.ccxt.com/en/latest/manual.html#margin) может это то, что вы искали?

Comment: Спасибо, буду изучать данную библиотеку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужный вам метод `POST /sapi/v1/margin/order` в этой библиотеке не реализован.  Но вы можете расширить класс `Binance\API` и использовать метод `httpRequest`.

Я не разбираюсь в предметной области, но будет что-то вроде:

```
class ExtendedAPI extends API {

    public function postOrderForMarginAccount() {
        $params = [
            'sapi' => true,
            // тут все необходимые параметры
        ];

        return $this->httpRequest('v1/margin/order', 'POST', $params, true);
    }

}
```

С аргументами такой функции, я думаю, вы разберётесь самостоятельно.

Comment: Спасибо! Да, попробую разобраться с аргументами.